# C# Task pass as a parameter to other task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

So i have currently such code:

```
//THIS IS A PART OF A METHOD
// ...
// Add a logic after the request has finished
(this.cache[RequestType.DeleteReceiver] as Task<Tuple<ServiceResponseCode, bool>>).ContinueWith((receiversDeletionTask) =>
{
     receiversDeletionTask.Wait();

     // Check that response was ok
     if (receiversDeletionTask.Result.Item1 == ServiceResponseCode.Ok && receiversDeletionTask.Result.Item2 == true)
     {
          ReceiverModel deletedReceiver = this.fetchedReceivers.Find(receiver => receiver.Id == id);
          this.fetchedReceivers.Remove(deletedReceiver);
          this.fetchedReceiversIndexes.RemoveAt(this.fetchedReceivers.IndexOf(deletedReceiver));
          foreach (int index in this.fetchedReceiversIndexes)
          {
              this.fetchedReceiversIndexes[index] = index;
          }
      }
});
return await (this.cache[RequestType.DeleteReceiver] as Task<Tuple<ServiceResponseCode, bool>>);
```

In this implementation i return the first task, and the caller begins to work after the first task finishes, but i wan't the caller, to wait for the ContinueWith task.

So i have tried to refactor to this:

```
Task receiversDeletionTask = this.cache[RequestType.DeleteReceiver] as Task<Tuple<ServiceResponseCode, bool>>;
Task receiverDeletionFromCacheTask = new Task((receiversDeletionTask) => { });
```

But, it prompts me: Delegate 'Action' does not take 1 arguments

I know that action doesn't take an argument. I need a way how to make his happen.

**I have a task that deletes the receiver on the server - receiversDeletionTask;
I need after finishing the receiversDeletionTask launch a method, that will remove the data from local cache.
And i need to return info only when the cache clearing method will finish.**

Comment: If you want the caller to wait for the continuation task, then you should await and return the continuation task, no?

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, i need to wait for it, but how to refactor the code to do so? I need 2  task to run after 1 task, and the caller should await for the 2 task

Comment: The `ContinueWith` method returns the Task object for the continuation task. I have no idea what and why you want to refactor. Instead of awaiting and returning `this.cache[RequestType.DeleteReceiver]` just take the task object provided by `ContinueWith` and await and return this task object. Do i perhaps misunderstand you?

Comment: (You might perhaps need to modfiy your continuation task method so that it returns data the caller awaiting this task might want/need.)

Comment: @elgonzo "The ContinueWith method returns the Task object for the continuation task" - i think i missed this. Let me try it

Comment: @elgonzo seems like you are correct. i have just mised that when you call .ContinueWith - it returns the continuation task